# Label text change when button is selected (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
   #Frame for displaying message to user about critque status
    frame_two=tk.Frame(entertainment_critique_window, width=622, height=140,    highlightbackground= 'black', highlightthickness=6)
    frame_two.grid(row=0, column=2,sticky='N', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=10,ipady=10, columnspan=2)
    frame_two.grid_propagate(False)

    radiobutton_variable = StringVar(entertainment_critique_window, 1)


    def update_status():
    l2.config(text='you have selected ' + str(radiobutton_variable.get()))

    l1=Label(frame_two, text="Critique Status:", fg='white', font=('Comic Sans',45, 'bold'))
    l1.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='NW',padx=0,pady=0)
    l2=Label(frame_two, text="Please select from the following options below", fg='white', font=. ('Comic Sans',27,))
    l2.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='E',padx=50,pady=20)

    #Frame for displaying 3 Media (entertainment) options
    frame_three=tk.Frame(entertainment_critique_window, width=642, height=200,
    highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=6)
    frame_three.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='NE', padx=5,pady=175)
    frame_three.grid_propagate(False)

    
    r1=tk.Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Cinema - Hoyts", variable = radiobutton_variable,    value="Cinema - Hoyts", command=update_status)
    r1.grid(row = 4, column = 0,pady=15)

    r2=tk.Radiobutton(frame_three, text="TV  - Channel 7", variable = radiobutton_variable, value="TV  - Channel 7", command=update_status)
    r2.grid(row = 5, column = 0,pady=15)

    r3=tk.Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Radio - Nova 100", variable = radiobutton_variable, value="Radio - Nova 100", command=update_status)
    r3.grid(row = 6, column = 0,pady=15)


  

    button=Button(frame_three,text="Show Details",height=1)
    button.place(x=462,y=50,)

    button=Button(frame_three, text="Show Summary",height=1)
    button.place(x=455,y=120,)




    #Frame for User to provide rating of selected option
    frame_four=tk.Frame(entertainment_critique_window, width=642, height=130,
    highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=6)
    frame_four.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='NE', padx=5,pady=415)
    frame_four.grid_propagate(False)

    l3=Label(frame_four, text="Rating Number:", fg='white', font=('Comic Sans',35, 'bold'))
    l3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='NW',padx=0,pady=0)

    button_save=Button(frame_four, text="Save Critique",width=10,height=1)
    button_save.place(x=495,y=12,)

    spinbox1= Spinbox(frame_four, from_=0, to=10, width=15)
    spinbox1.place(x=300,y=14,)

   # Start the event loop to detect user inputs
    entertainment_critique_window.mainloop()
```

Id like for the label called L2 which displays "Please select from the following options below" to display "Your critique has been saved".

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  Best is to paste the *tested code that reproduces the problem* between triple-backtick (```) lines.

Comment: So what stopping you from doing it as you hnow how to update a label?

Comment: Right.  That's EXACTLY what you're doing in the `update_status` function.

Comment: I've tried following the same format but it's not working

Comment: *"it's not working"* doesn't tell much to us to identify the problem.  Did you get any error on the console? Is the text of the label not changed?  Also the posted code is not a [mre].

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-variable" this is the error i get & it stops my program from running

Comment: As said, you need to provide a [mre] and better to post the full error traceback in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like for the label called L2 which displays "Please select from
> the following options below" to display "Your critique has been saved"

Create a function called `save_status()`.

```
def save_status():
    l2.config(text='Your critique has been saved')

:
:
:
button_save=Button(frame_four, text="Save Critique", command=save_status, width=10,height=1)
button_save.place(x=495,y=12,)
```

Comment: toyota Supra, thanks for the solution. Would u know how to return the text to normal after the critique has been made.

Comment: Same function., you will write l2.config(text='Please select from the following option')  root.after(x, save_status) x denote delay time.